# App crashed when i build a signed APK with jsoup

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

My android app was crashing when i build a signed apk. The crash was not seen when i did a debug build. The build.gradle file is like this:

```
buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled true
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

setting `minifyEnabled` to `false` is not the correct solution, that would disable proguard while building the release version

The reason why setting `minifyEnabled` is working is because proguard might be obfuscating jsoup.
So, you should keep `minifyEnabled` as `true` and include these rules for jsoup in your proguard-rules.txt file to prevent the app from crashing :

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
    public *;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What i did to prevent the app from crashing is that i have made minifyEnabled to false from true in the build.gradle file. In that file i have made the following change.

```
    buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

If anybody have any other answers please post it here.

Comment: making the minifyEnabled false will prevent the app from crashing but the correct implementation is the answer given by Ashish.