# Android studio gradle error, "configuration with name default not found" with aviary sdk

Tags: android

First of all, I know there are a lot of subjects about this problems, but I still can't fix it.

I'm just trying to customize aviary sdk by following the guide here : https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/setup-guide#  (section 4.2, not 4.1)

here are my **root gradle** files :

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle :

```
include ':app', ':Aviary-Android-Sample-App'
```

here is my **app build.gradle** file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.agaze.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile project(':Aviary-Android-Sample-App')
}
```

Here my files tree:

[image: My files tree]

Thanks in advance for your tips.

Antonin

Comment: You must make the minifyEnabled to true. minifyEnabled false would disable proguard while building the release version

The reason why setting minifyEnabled is working is because proguard might be obfuscating the external library file.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081077/app-crashed-when-i-build-a-signed-apk-with-jsoup

Answer (score 0):

Check your submodules and make sure each submodule in your project has its own build.gradle file. 
Check this guide for more info
[tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Each library you add to your project should have it's own `build.gradle` file. If it does not have you can get this error.

For a solution you can add your sdk as a module with Android Studio. To do this you can follow the path in Android Studio:

`File > New > Import Module` and select directory of your sdk and add to your project.

Select `Gradle System` and let Android Studio create gradle files for your sdk.

You can check the link below for more information and how to add a module to your project.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/

I hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your screen shot.It's obvious that the Aviary-Android-Sample-App is an eclipse project(no gradle file there) but not a valid gradle module.

If you want to import it into android studio, in android studio, click File -> new module -import eclipse adt project and go on under the instruction.

And you are good to go.

Edit: 
Also, it seems that you want to modified the Aviary sdk, but the module you want to import is a sample app. Maybe you have downloaded the wrong file. The correct link looks like this one https://creativesdk.adobe.com/downloads.html